# Magento 2.3.4 EE Companies edit not finding the company

Tags: magento-enterprise, exception, magento2.3.4, magento2-b2b

I am trying to edit companies using the "Edit" link at the right of the grid of companies.

The link the link is trying to get to is as follows

`/admin/company/index/edit/id/4/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

The id number is valid when I look in the company DB table. I have tried this for any of the companies and I get the same result.

I am getting an exception thrown

> The requested company is not found

I have started to work my way through the code in the `/vendor/magento/module-customer` module and I am about to start code tracing to see what is going on.

Has anyone else come across a similar situation where the company is not found when trying to edit? I am asking to try to save myself hours of hair pulling

Answer (score 0):

@richard-luckhurst I had the same problem, but I could edit the company after to follow this step:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/account-company-manage.html#activate-company-accounts

```
Activate company accounts
Set the Actions control to Set Active.

When prompted to confirm, click OK.
```

Comment: Hi @Marcelo did you get any solution for this issue? I am getting the same.